# Imported DB - Add Migration - Add table column for a already available table tries to create the table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have imported a database through a .bacpac to my local. In the C# solution project I have added a column to an existing table(Entity). The connection string in the solution is set to the database in my local machine. The database has the table "_EFMigrationHistory".

When I try to Add Migration and update the database, the code generated for the migration tries to create the tables listed under the DBContext in my local database.

Then I get an error saying

> "There is already an object named 'TableName' in the database."

In the migration code, it looks like it tries to create the already available tables in the DB.
But my need is to only update the column change which I applied in the DBSet in the code. I dont want to loose the data in my local db.
How is it possible only to push the table column update without creating all the tables again?
Would appreciate some help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out your column change (what you actually want to migrate later) and run the following command via Powershell

```
Add-Migration SnapshotCreate
```

Since this migration is *only* used to get the ModelSnapshot.cs file up to date, you can just delete the migration file (something like `{Date}SnapshotCreate.cs`).

Next, uncomment out your column change and then add your migration like normal. This should only pull in your `Up` and `Down` changes for that column.